# Python - log one last exit message before exiting

Tags: python, logging, python-3.7

I have some logger module that I wrote (it inherits from `logging.Logger`, but I don't think it's an important detail for the discussion)

I want to write a final message before exiting, this message will contain info about how long it took since the script started, and so on. It should work when the script exits normally, when `sys.exit()` is called, and when an uncaught exception is raised (e.g assert failed).

I'm not sure what is the correct way to do that. I'm considering using a global that will write the message upon `__del__`, but I know in python it's not always called. I considered using `atexit` but I'm not sure if it's guaranteed to be called, and whether imported modules will be available (I want to be able to write my messages to a remote server as well).

I'm using Python3.7

Comment: Can you wrap all the code with `try` and then `except SystemExit` can do some final work before `sys.exit()`. You could also use a `try/except/finally` setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `atexit` module. It works with exceptions and `sys.exit`

```py
import atexit
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

time_start = None

def main():
    global time_start
    time_start = datetime.now()
    sleep(2)
    atexit.register(log_total_time)


def log_total_time():
    print('Elapsed:',datetime.now() - time_start)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output:

```
Elapsed: 0:00:02.417707
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html